# Javascript Selected Anchor

Tags: javascript, anchor

I'm not sure if I have seen this right but using the jQuery UI Themeroller the current theme settings seem to be stored in the URL like http://www.site.com/page.html#theme-details...

Is there a way to extract the data from this using javascript? So I would return something like

```
theme-details...
```

From the URL I just mentioned

Or have I got it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the fragment identifier of the current document’s URL:

```
location.hash
```

And if you want it of a string:

```
str.match(/^[^#]*#(.*)/)[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
window.location.hash
```

will return the part of the URL that follows the # symbol, including the # symbol.

```
window.location.hash.substring(1);
```

will return theme-details...

See more on

```
window.location
```

[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location)

Answer (score 1):

```
document.location.hash.substring(1) // will return "theme-details" minus the hash
```